# Control caching in SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language mode

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use "SQL Expression Language" mode for interaction with a DB from TWO apps.
The 1st writes changes, the 2nd - reads.
In both applications DB connection are created at the start and are not disposed.

Problem: The app which reads from the DB doesn't see changes from the app which writes data which are made after the reader start, until the reading app is restarted. How to control when cache is used?

The DB is Mysql if it matters. and Alchemy is 1.4

I presume that there is a result cache in "SQL Expression Language" which prevents re-reading data from the DB, but I don't find any clear mention about that in the documentation, although there is a lot of mentions about caching for the ORM mode (which I don't use).

Comment: Probably the isolation level of the db connection prevents changes being visible unless the connection is committed.

Comment: Thanks. The level is the default one and I see changes from another CLI client.

Comment: "I presume that there is a result cache in 'SQL Expression Language' which prevents re-reading data from the DB" - No, there isn't. If you `.execute()` a query in SQLAlchemy Core that query is always sent to the server.

Comment: snakecharmerb and gord-thompson you both were right. When I set read-commited the problem's gone. Thank you!